# Calculating the area of Triangle

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the area of triangle formed by the lines $x^2+4xy+y^2=0$ and $x+y=1$.

I know that the equation $x^2+4xy+y^2=0$ represents a pair of straight lines but how do i factorize it to get the two lines represented by it.

Comment: Write $y=mx$ and solve for $m$.

Comment: Use the quadratic equation to get two "solutions" for y.  Those should make two linear equations.

Comment: @fleablood I got it using quad. equation formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x^2+4xy+y^2=x^2+2xy+y^2+2xy$ so, taking into account the other equation, you get $1+2xy=0$.

So you are reduced to finding two numbers $x$ and $y$ of which you know the sum, because $x+y=1$, and the product, because $xy=-1/2$.

Such numbers are the roots of the quadratic equation
$$
z^2-z-\frac{1}{2}=0
$$
that is,
$$
\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2} \quad\text{or}\quad \frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$
So you have two points
$$
\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
\qquad
\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)
$$
and the third vertex is the unique point of intersection of the pair of lines represented by $x^2+4xy+y^2$, which is the origin. Then the area of the triangle is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left|\det\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2} & \dfrac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}\\[6px]
\dfrac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2} & \dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\right|=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{4+2\sqrt{3}}{4}-\frac{4-2\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)
=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$

---

You may enjoy proving the fact that, if $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are two points, then the area of the triangle having those points and the origin as the vertices is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left|\det\begin{bmatrix}a & c\\b&d\end{bmatrix}\right|
=
\frac{1}{2}|ad-bc|
$$

You can prove it by using the fact that the line passing through $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ has equation
$$
(b-d)(x-c)-(a-c)(y-d)=0
$$
that can also be written as
$$
(b-d)x-(a-c)y+(ad-bc)=0
$$
and so the distance of this line from the origin is
$$
h=\frac{|(b-d)\cdot0-(a-c)\cdot0+(ad-bc)|}{\sqrt{(b-d)^2+(a-c)^2}}
=
\frac{|ad-bc|}{\sqrt{(b-d)^2+(a-c)^2}}
$$
and that the denominator is exactly the distance between the two points. So, taking this segment as the basis, and multiplying by the height $h$, we get that the area is
$$
\frac{1}{2}|ad-bc|
$$
What for a general triangle having vertices at $(x_0,y_0)$, $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$? Just do a translation and consider the congruent triangle having one vertex at the origin and the other two at $(x_1-x_0,y_1-y_0)$ and $(x_2-x_0,y_2-y_0)$. Then the area is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left|\det
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1-x_0 & x_2-x_0 \\
y_1-y_0 & y_2-y_0
\end{bmatrix}
\right|=
\frac{1}{2}\left|\det
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0 & x_1 & x_2 \\
y_0 & y_1 & y_2 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\right|
$$

For the last formula, compute the determinant of the $3\times3$ matrix by first adding to the first row the third one multiplied by $-x_0$, then adding to the second row the third one multiplied by $-y_0$, getting the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & x_1-x_0 & x_2-x_0 \\
0 & y_1-y_0 & y_2-y_0 \\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
These operations don't change the determinant. Now use Laplace on the first column.

Comment: Could you please explain me the formula for the area of triangle that you have used? I am not familiar with this..

Comment: @Iaamuseruser I added a derivation for it.

Comment: I understood and in what other conditions can this formula be used?

Comment: @Iaamuseruser In any situation where you need the area of a triangle having the origin as one of its vertices. For a general triangle, do a translation, I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $y-m_1x=0$ & $y-m_2x=0$ be the straight lines passing through the origin  represented by $x^2+4xy+y^2=0$ then it can be factorize as follows 
$$x^2+4xy+y^2=(y-m_1x)(y-m_2x)$$
$$m_1m_2x^2-(m_1+m_2)xy+y^2=x^2+4xy+y^2$$
comparing the corresponding coefficients on both the sides, one should get $$m_1m_2=1\tag 1$$
$$m_1+m_2=-4\tag 2$$
solving (1) & (2), one should get 
$m_1=-2-\sqrt 2$ & $m_2=-2+\sqrt 3$

hence, the pair of lines is $\color{blue}{y=(-2-\sqrt3)x}$ & $\color{blue}{y=(-2+\sqrt3)x}$

Now, solve the three equations: $\color{}{y=(-2-\sqrt3)x}$, $\color{}{y=(-2+\sqrt3)x}$ & $x+y=1$ to find coordinate of the vertices & then apply formula for area of triangle having vertices $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$ & $(x_3, y_3)$
$$=\frac 12\left|x_1(y_2-y_3)+x_2(y_3-y_1)+x_3(y_1-y_2)\right|$$

Comment: now it becomes easy

Comment: i got the answer as $√3/2$ , is it correct?

Comment: Actually, I have not made the complete calculations however you can re-check it to confirm the answer. Your answer  may be right.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** The symmetry in $x, y$ of the quadratic expression suggests that we can eliminate the cross term by substituting $x = s - t, y = s + t$. Indeed, substituting and simplifying gives in these coordinates that the quadratic equation is
$$6 s^2 - 2 t^2 = 0 ,$$
but this is a difference of perfect squares, and so is easy to factor.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

solving $x^2+4xy+y^2=0$ with respect to y you find:
$$
y=-2x\pm x\sqrt{3}
$$
so you can factorize.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, complete the square:

$$x^2+4xy+y^2=(x+2y)^2-3y^2=(x+2y-\sqrt3y)(x+2y+\sqrt3y).$$

---

More generally,

$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2=a(x^2+\frac b{2a})^2+\left(c-\frac{b^2}{4a}\right)y^2=a\left(x+\frac{b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}y\right )\left(x+\frac{b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}y\right).$$